# Creating a file in TCL on windows

Tags: tcl

It seems like this code should work...

```
set data "sample text"
set file_name "C:\Test2.txt"
set file_obj [open $file_name w]
puts -nonewline $file_obj $data
close $file_obj
```

But no file is created on either of my systems.

```
set file_name "C:\Test2.txt"
file exists $file_name
```

Comes back as 1 (true) while the file does not exist whatsoever. Confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is probably created, not in the root directory of C: but in the current directory. You see, the way the Tcl interpreter treats backslashes in a double-quoted string is to convert it and the following character to a special character (such as `\t`, which gets converted to a tab character, and `\n`, which becomes a newline). When the interpreter looks at the string `"C:\Test2.txt"` it finds the combination `\T`, which isn't a valid escape code, so it evaluates the string to just `"C:Test2.txt"`, which is a legal file name in Windows, meaning `Test2.txt` in the current directory of C:.

The solution is to instead use Unix-style regular slashes in your file names, such as `"C:/Test2.txt"`.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, use double-backslash `"C:\\Test2.txt"` or put in braces `{C:\Test2.txt}`. A good way to check that the filename is what is expected is to do `puts $file_name`…